# Extracting and merging PDFs via Pypdf2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I am a little stuck. I am trying to merge and extract the text from all the PDF files in a working directory. Then I would like to store the data in a CSV form to run additional analysis on it. However I keep getting a `PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found` error. I have checked the resources however I am still struggling.

```
import PyPDF2
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

merger = PdfFileMerger()
for filename in os.listdir():
    with open(filename,"rb") as source:
        tmp = PdfFileReader(source)
        merger.append(tmp)

tmp.write('tmp.csv', 'wb')
tmp.close()
```

Comment: When does this error occur? Are you sure all the PDFs in the folder are valid? Can Adobe/Acrobat Reader read them all?

Comment: excuse me, error occurs on line tmp = PdfFileReader(source). and all the files are readable

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's some small mistake in your code, you are creating `tmp` variable `inside the loop` but using it `outside for writing to csv` . And also, as per my knowledge you don't need to create `with open and then create a PdfFileReader object` for merging. Try to use this simple approach for merging multiple `pdf-files`:

```
import PyPDF2
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdffile in os.listdir():
    merger.append(pdffile)

merger.write('tmp.csv')
merger.close()
```

Comment: Thank you that helps very much. I am now getting an error stating:PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found most likely one of my files are truncated. Is there a good way to handle this error?

Comment: @Meredith: Doesn't sound like all the files are readable. Regardless, the standard way to handle exceptions in Python is by putting the line with the potential error inside a `try`/`except` and handling the problem in the `except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError:` clause (which can be to just ignore it with `pass`).

Comment: If you are  getting `EOF error ` after using this code also, it means some of your `pdf` might be corrupt, and not having `%EOF` character . You can try the `try/except` approach as suggested by @MeredithJackson to fix the problem. You can also first try to find out which file is having this problem,  using `print of filename` statements inside your exception block.

Comment: Onces used the try statement it just skipped over it and I got it working thanks again!